# Set-theoretical semantics vs categorical semantics

Tags: logic, category-theory, model-theory

Yo! I'm trying to understand the relation between set theoretical models (in the usual Tarskian sense) and categorical models. I don't care whether you gonna use the hyperdoctrine of the subobjects or the one given by the slice categories. I'm fine with an answer using any of these.

I will use arithmetic as a toy model to test such relation.

Let $\mathcal{C}_{HA}$ be the syntactic category of the Heyting  arithmetic $HA$.

Explicitly, $\mathcal{C}_{HA}$ has one object $N$ all finite products, a morphism $0: 1 \rightarrow N$ and a morphism $s (n) : 1 \rightarrow N$ for every $n : 1\rightarrow N$.

At first, it looks like that $\mathcal{C}_{HA}$ is very the analogous of the standard model of the natural numbers, but this is obviously false as $\mathcal{C}_{HA}$ validates only what's already provable.

Externally, by definition, every $1 \rightarrow N$ is necessarily of the form $s^m (0) : 1 \rightarrow N$ for some (metatheorical) natural number $m$. However one can't prove it internally as it would infer that $HA$ can prove its consistency. So categorical semantics is somehow more theoretical than usual set theoretical semantics.

Take for instance, the Gödel sentence $G \cong \forall (n : N) (\neg Prov (n, [G]))$. Then the usual proof that it's valid on the standard naturals is by validating each instance $\neg Prov (0, [G])$, $\neg Prov (1, [G])$, $\neg Prov (2, [G])$ etc. That is the $\forall$ is external and it's somehow preserved by the "morphism" from the metatheory to the theory (the theory of the categorical interpretation underlying the standard natural numbers).

In contrast, in categorical semantics the $\forall$ is strictly internal and given by the right adjoint of the change of variables functor.

Another difference is that the standard natural numbers model is initial among the set-theoretical models, however, as noticed above, it cannot be initial among the categorical models.

So the general question is

1) What's the relation between set-theoretical semantics and categorical semantics?

It seems that simply restricting to the $\mathbf{Set}$ valued categorical interpretations wouldn't answer the question as $\mathbf{Set}$ always validates the excluded middle.

The minor questions are

2) What's the categorical version of the standard natural numbers model?

There seems to be a problem if such model is simply given by the obvious set valued interpretation given by setting the object $N$ (as above in the case of $\mathcal{C}_{HA}$) equals to the standard natural numbers as an object of $\mathbf{Set}$. The problem is that it seems to validate that every natural is canonical, which seems to imply consistency of the theory underlying such category. Furthermore such model if interpreted in $\mathbf{Set}$ would always validate the excluded middle as $\mathbf{Set}$ is Boolean.

3) What's the initial model for set theoretical semantics in general (for any theory)?

In the categorical case, it's always given by the syntactic category, however I have no idea about the set theoretical case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this but I think one of the points of categorical semantics is that you have an initial model, whereas in general you don't have a set theoretic initial model

Comment: @Max One can always try to make a model by adding an element for every sentence of the theory, but I've heard that it may fail to be a model unless the theory is Henkin complete. I can't see now why it fails though.

Comment: I am unable to tell if you're confusing several different notions here, or just being a bit loose with the language. The syntactic category isn't a model, though it may contain a generic model; usually the term "model" is reserved for particular functors that have the syntactic category as their domain. Any set theoretic model is just going to be the special case of the categorical semantics applied to $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I'm using a loose language. You can take a categorical model as any logical functor  from the syntactic category to some category or, equivalently, you can take a categorical model by interpreting symbols suitably inside the category. In this case, the identity functor would be the syntactic category as a model in my loose language. About your second statement, I have no idea why this would be the case as $\mathbf{Set}$ is always Boolean. How would one interpret $HA$, for instance, as a functor $\mathcal{C}_{HA} \rightarrow Set$ without validating the excluded middle?

Comment: Perhaps I'm exposing an insufficient understanding of the topic by asking this, but why wouldn't you expect a model of HA in $\mathbf{Set}$ to satisfy excluded middle? A classical model of HA (i.e. a model of PA) is still a model of HA, so nothing has gone wrong with it as a model of HA as such; you're just interpreting it in a category that imposes stronger properties on the model than other categories might, right?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine The point is that set theoretical models of HA (in the non-categorical sense) don't always satisfy the excluded middle. So restricting to categorical models valued in $\mathbf{Set}$ won't give you all the set theoretical models. Therefore such non classical categorical models must be valued elsewhere, but I'm not sure where exactly. Maybe it's some kind of realizability topoi.

Comment: I think that's the crux of it: properly intuitionistic models that can be constructed through set theoretic means are not models, in the usual sense, in the category of sets. A Kripke model over a poset of possible worlds $K$, for example, is essentially a model in the usual sense in the category of sheaves on the up-set topology for $K$. But I'm not sure how to get more general than that without some very different machinery using fibrations... Now that I understand it better, though, it's a very good question.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Yes, you have to change the way you interpret the negation (or the implication), so in the end you get a Kripke model or a realizability model. I've forgotten about it actually. Now I think that I can solve the question. Thanks for the remark.